# Server Disconnected Error: python with postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, dask-to-sql

I'm trying to upload some heavy data in postgresql from dask python but it's giving the following error: Server Disconnected. Can anyone help me?

code:

base_SP.to_sql('SIPNI_SP2', 'postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/vacinacao',if_exists='replace', index = False, chunksize=1000, dtype = sqlalchemy.VARCHAR ,  method='multi',compute=True, parallel=False)

Comment: Trying to remove the obvious: is the Postgres server running?

Comment: yes, the server is running. I can import smaller datasets

Comment: Oh, maybe there's a timeout which needs to be set to a higher value. Try running `show statement_timeout;` from psql and see if that's some low value. If it's set to zero there's no limit, and this is not the issue.